# Assigning Different Controller To DOM Depending on Boolean Field in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Is this possible? That is, can I choose which controller is bound with a DOM, depending on a certain Boolean value that is queried from database?

Comment: I think you could accomplish this using an HTML templating language. Some  popular ones are [EJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) or [pug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug)(formerly [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/)). Look into using variables, interpolation, and/or conditionals to switch which controller will be used depending on the Boolean.